# $.post function in jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Im using laravel5.1 with jquery, and Im trying to use ajax to submit a form. What's wrong with my code? Im just using the simple ajax request to post a data. Please see my code below.

```
<div id="result"></div>
<form action="" method="post" id="create">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="description" class="control-label">Description</label>
      <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success">
   </div>
   {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

**route**

```
Route::post('/ajax-push', [
    'as' => 'ajax-push',
    'uses' => 'PagesController@postAjaxCreate'
]);
```

**Controller**

```
public function postAjaxCreate(Request $request){
        echo 'Hello there!';
    }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = '{{ route('ajax-push') }}';
    $('#create').on('submit', function(){
        $.post(url, function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: "not working" ... what do you expect to happen? what do you observe instead? debugging 101: Check the developer tools console (F12 in most browsers) for errors. Are there any errors in the console? If so, what are they?

Comment: I would recommend `$('#create').on('submit', function(){ ... rest of code ...})` changed to `$('#create').on('submit', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ... rest of code ...})`

Comment: I don't Laravel, but... usually (in most frameworks) JS is typically served statically, not passed through the template engine... Check in Inspector whether your JS has a correct `var url =`? Check Network if any AJAX request is initiated? Check on server if a request came in?... Lots of possible debugging steps. Also, what data are you posting? Is your CSRF token getting sent at all?

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, I expected to see the "Hello there!" string in the `#result` id. I've also tried to use the `preventDefault` function, but still no changes.

Comment: You need to prevent default form submission behavior. In your form submit event, pass event as argument and prevent it. function (e) { e.preventDefault();}

Comment: @Jonjie - what else do you observe in the browser developer tools console? Is a request made when you click the button? If so, what is the request?

Comment: I have an error, `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:` in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try

```
$_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
$.post( url, { _token: $_token })
.done(function( data )
{
     $('#result').html(data);
});
```

But personally I use it in this way:

put this in the header

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

and this on the script

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
       'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

then i make the ajax calls:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: "{{ route("a.route") }}",
       data: $("#form").serialize(),
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (datos) {
           //mycode
       },
       error: function (request, status, error) {
           console.log(error);
       }
   });
```

Comment: What's the difference of this? Is this better to use? are there any advantages of using this?

Comment: I really dont know if there is a difference. Maybe somebody else can tell us. I think is not a difference, just two ways to do the same.

Comment: Ooh, great. Do you have any links/tutorial for this $.ajax() method with laravel?